# Derivative of a vector by a matrix

Tags: partial-derivative

I have an equation describing feedforward process for MLP:
$$
  \textbf{g}_j = \textbf{W}_j \times \textbf{h}_{j-1} + \textbf{b}_j
$$ 
$$
  \textbf{h}_j = \sigma_j (\textbf{g}_j)
$$ 
then in order to use gradient descent we need to find next partial derivative for weights of matrix $W_j $ :
$$
C = \frac {1}{2} ||h_L - y||^2
$$
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial \textbf{W}_j} = \frac{\partial C}{\partial \textbf{g}_j} \times \frac{\partial \textbf{g}_j}{\partial \textbf{W}_j} = 
\frac{\partial C}{\partial \textbf{g}_j} \times \textbf{h}^T_{j-1}
$$
where 
$
y,h_j,g_j,b_j \in R^n, W_j \in R^{n \times n}, j \in [1,L]
$

And I'm struggling to figure out why $h_j$ is transposed and how in general case is differentiation of vector by a matrix accomplished?

Comment: what is $C$? ...

Comment: Read this notes on linear algebra of Andrew Ng, http://cs229.stanford.edu/section/cs229-linalg.pdf